"Perhaps if I followed, I would find more of my kind." Is this just a past form?

I discovered a fallen statue of a race that resembled my own. Though it had collapsed from many years of decay, it still marked the way to those who had built it. Perhaps if I followed, I would find more of my kind.

In this paragraph above, is the last sentence just a past tense form of "Perhaps if I follow, I will find more of my kind"?

Not quite. Would means in theory, maybe, hypothetically, depending. We can say the sun will rise tomorrow, but will I see it? That depends. If I face East, I would find the sun beautiful.

It is a backshift to past-tense to mark the hypothetical nature of the clause.

At the time, the speaker thought "Perhaps if I follow, I will...". Because the narrative is in the past, the thoughts are also given in the past tense.

The last sentence shows the conditional "If (past tense)   I {subject} would..."
This is sometimes called a "second condition". It expresses a hypothesis which is thought to be untrue in the present. The hypothesis is "If I followed", But at the time of the narration, the speaker hasn't followed. However the author is setting up an opportunity for the protagonist to make a decision (to follow or not to follow)

I always thought the "second condition" talks about the present or near future, like, "If I won the lottery, I would buy a big house." is something you'd say thinking about right now or the hypothetical future. The paragraph I wrote above came from a video game, called Aquaria. Almost all of the quotes from that game are talking about the past and have past tense because the plot is basically the protagonist recalling what happened. But do you steel interpret "I would find more of my kind" as any other second condition sentences?
